# What are specific cartoon-type interjections like "cough" and "sigh" called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, interjections

In comics, for example those by Walt Disney, interjections that describe or emphasize in words what the characters in the image are doing are quite commonly used (*cough*, *sigh*, *tweet*).

According to the *[German Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv)*, a grammatical term for this type of word has been introduced only recently, in 1998. It’s called *Inflektiv*.

I could not find an English translation, neither on these pages nor in any search engine. Is there a term for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [German Wikipedia page for *Inflektiv*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflektiv) also provides a synonym—[Erikativ](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Erikativ)—which is "named for Erika Fuchs, who translated Mickey Mouse comics into German and used the form frequently". Going by Google's results, *Erikativ* (or *Ericativ*, sometimes with an 'e' at the end) appears to be just as popular as *Inflektiv*.

There is an [interesting (and exhaustive) paper by a Mark Lindsay](http://www.linguistics.stonybrook.edu/sites/default/files/uploads/u3/lindsay_erikative.pdf) [PDF] on the subject of the *Erikativ* from a linguistic point of view. He states:

> The German *Erikativ* construction (also known as the *Inflektiv* (Teuber 1998)) is a phenomenon that existed prior to the mid-twentieth century, but first developed widespread prominence through the German-language translations of Disney comics during the 1950’s. The translator, Erika Fuchs, used this form to describe sounds and actions of the characters (not unlike English crash! or pow!); eventually, these words evolved beyond onomatopoeic use, expanding to phrases like stare (*starr*) or dancing while sitting (*sitzendtanz*). Unlike onomatopoeias, these new forms followed a predictable pattern.
>
> It should be noted that Teuber (1998, p. 8) describes the *Inflektiv* as a **verb form that is non-inflected** (German: nicht-flektiert); therefore, the German term *Inflektiv* should be **translated into English as Uninflective**. To avoid the confusion this causes, I shall use the alternative term, **Erikativ**.

Later:

> Teuber (1998) argues convincingly that the *Erikativ* is a true verb form, as it has semantic and morphological *restrictions that distinguish it from the freeform nature of interjections*. Noting the common similarity between the *Erikativ* form and the verbal stem, he coins the term *Inflektiv* (‘**uninflective**’) to describe its *lack of overt inflection*.

The *Erikativ* is essentially the same as "**actions**" or "**[emotes](http://www.pilgrim.demon.co.uk/irc/guide.html#emote)**" ([WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emote)) seen in most IRC channels and other chat rooms such as `*dies*`, `*dances*`, `*rolls his eyes*`, `*coughs*`, etc.

In comic lettering, *emotes*, when inserted within dialogue, are punctuated differently. These punctuations are called [breath marks, crow's feet, cat's whiskers, or fireflies](http://www.blambot.com/grammar.shtml). I am unaware of any standard term that describes the "*breath words*" themselves.

Comment: Nice elaboration! +1

Answer (score 3):

In scripts (which are used for cartoons, as well as plays and conventional films), instructions as to how a character is behaving, or the manner of his/her/its speech are called

> - personal directions
> - parentheticals
> - wrylies

See discussion [here](http://www.storysense.com/format/parentheticals.htm).

This category covers both simple action instructions

> *coughs*

as well as more extensive guidance

> *lifting eyebrow, stares at Janet wryly*

The derivation of each of the first two alternative terms is fairly obvious. The instruction is a direction to an individual actor (similar to a stage direction). It is enclosed in parentheses in the text of the script.

The term *wrylies* is probably [synecdoche](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/synecdoche), using the term *wryly* to stand in for all the emotive instructions given by playwrights or directors.

> FRANK
>   (wryly)
>   But I am your biggest fan.

Some actors find some of these instructions patronizing, suggesting that the actor does not understand the affect of the dialog.

SUPPLEMENT: The examples you give all use words that convey sounds. My recollection of cartoon style conjures up **POW** and **KRUNCHHH** and similar terms. Where a word is intended to imitate the sound it represents, is is called an [onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia). Since the cartoon terms sound like [interjections](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/interjection?view=uk) (even if they are not formally speech), I would suggest *onomatopoetic interjection*. Not one word, but a short descriptive phrase.

Comment: The question does not ask for a name for instructions in scripts. Though your post is interesting, it does not answer the question.

Comment: That's quite interesting, but I don't think your explanations refer to the word usage described in my question. The "Inflektiv" is rather a description of the characters action, not an instruction. "Cough" does not mean "Perform a cough" but "The character is coughing".

Answer (score 2):

In Russian these forms are called *[verbal interjections](https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/983/are-there-inflectives-in-russian)*. These are such interjections that can be used to indicate some action. Googling indicates that in linguistic articles written in English this term is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Words that spell out sounds, and often carry sensations or inflective meaning are called

> [Onomatopoeia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Onomatopoeia)

I can't tell that's what you're looking for.  You may be looking for a word that indicates these words when used in a script or similar impression.

Comment: Never heard that word, but it is definitely close and more catchy than *uninflective*.

Comment: @Olaf, kids love saying it.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've seen them called "unsound effects" or the like.