# Term for written paralanguage?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography, phrase-requests

Is there a term for words filling in for body language (*sigh*) and/or for typography being used to express tone or intonation (THIS IS SHOUTING)?

Comment: These are really two separate questions, the first one being a duplicate of [How are specific cartoon-type interjections like “cough” and “sigh” called in English?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/83848/how-are-specific-cartoon-type-interjections-like-cough-and-sigh-called-in-en)

Comment: A tremendous literary example of this occurs in [Alfred Bester’s *The Stars My Destination*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination#Reception_and_influence).

Comment: There is a word for this, and I know I've encountered it in the past, but it's not coming to me. I've been mining my OED for some reference to it, but thus far this word eludes me. I'll come back if I find it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can call it [Emphasis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29)?

Answer (score 0):

To me, these are like interjected [stage directions](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stage_direction) but there are a couple words people use to describe embedding actions or emotions in text.

When in the first person, they are typically called "emotes". Elsewhere, they are more likely to be called "inflectives". Perhaps there is a better word that can capture the more kinesic meaning a sentence can be given.

Comment: Doesn't emote refer to acting and the spoken word rather than written language?

Comment: @5arx Yes, that is the classical definition. [The age of internet chat has morphed it a bit.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emote)